# How to call a member function on a parameter with std::for_each and boost::bind?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, boost, stl, boost-bind

I want to add a series of strings to a combo box using std::for_each. The objects are of type `Category` and I need to call `GetName` on them. How can I achieve this with `boost::bind`?

```
const std::vector<Category> &categories = /**/;
std::for_each(categories.begin(), categories.end(), boost::bind(&CComboBox::AddString, &comboBox, _1);
```

The current code fails as it's trying to call `CComboBox::AddString(category)`. Which is obviously wrong. How can I call `CComboBox::AddString(category.GetName())` using the current syntax?

Comment: Is there a strict necessity of using `std::foreach` instead of iterating?

Comment: Not a strict necessity, just trying to learn boost.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
std::for_each(categories.begin(), categories.end(), boost::bind(&CComboBox::AddString, &comboBox, boost::bind(&Category::GetName, _1)));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use lambdas, either [Boost.Lambda](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/lambda.html) or C++ lambdas (if your compiler supports them):

```
// C++ lambda
const std::vector<Category> &categories = /**/;
std::for_each(categories.begin(), categories.end(),
              [&comboBox](const Category &c) {comboBox.AddString(c.GetName());});
```

Comment: Thanks for those suggestions, VS2008 doesn't support lambdas though (I guess I should have specified that in the tags).

Comment: VS2008 supports Boost.Lambda.

Comment: Anyway, I removed the Boost.Lambda example since it was incorrect and a correct one would look more like the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

I know you asked about using std::for_each, but in those cases I like using BOOST_FOREACH instead, it makes the code more readable (in my opinion) and easier to debug:

```
const std::vector<Category> &categories = /**/;
BOOST_FOREACH(const Category& category, categories)
    comboBox.AddString(category.GetName());
```

Comment: +1 from me. BOOST_FOREACH is an incredibly cool feat. The inventor Eric Niebler wrote an article describing it: http://www.artima.com/cppsource/foreach.html. Minor nitpick, if you use braces it becomes more clear how incredibly cool BOOST_FOREACH is.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to achieve this would be using `mem_fun` and `bind1st`